# Coloring css shapes with different colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a solution to color some css shapes (don't really want to use svg as in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/widged/4545199 , but the output would be pretty similar). What I need moreover is having these shapes saved with their ID's in different color arrays.

In my example I'm using div's with id's *asd* and *fgh*. I want to choose the color from the square on the left and color the squares I select on the right with clicking on them so the color would change to the one previously selected.

And I need some method of storing which of the square is assigned to which colour. Later then I would have to pass this data to php, but I will be able to manage to do this alone, I guess. The example is [here](http://shrt.edu.pl/beta/teeth/new/i4.php).

And the sources:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<script>
var colors = ["white","red","blue","green","yellow","purple"];
var index = 0;
function button_click() {
   index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
   document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="box" onclick="button_click();"></div>
<div class="t1" id="asd"></div>
<div class="t1" id="fgh"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

mystyle.css

```
div#box
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    float: left;
}
.t1
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: black;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    float: right;
}
```

Waiting for both examples and suggestions :)

Solution:

```
function paint(color,id) {
    var currentID = id;
    document.getElementById(currentID).style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

and

```
<div class="t1" id="asd" onclick="paint(colors[index],this.id);"></div>
```

Comment: your waiting on examples and suggestions... we're all waiting on what you've tried that isnt working?

Comment: you're right. edited

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is exactly your question, but I think that you are asking about to get the current color to pass through PHP, huh?

```
 function getCurrentColor() {
      var color = document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor;
      // you can now use AJAX or a form to pass this value to php
```

## EDIT

OP was explained better in comment.
You can:

```
 // add style to 3 boxes
 function button_click() {
     index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
     document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
     document.getElementById("asd").style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
     document.getElementById("fgh").style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
 }


 // returns the current color of #box
 function getColor() {
        return document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor;
 }

 function whichIsColor(color) {
       // select all elements
       var els = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
       //iterate through them
       for(var i in els) {
            // if matches the color passed in argument:
            if(els[i].style.backgroundColor === color) {
               return els[i];
            }
       } 
 }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a way to
1) access currently chosen color globally by js
2) use it to paint the other 2 squares with different id's
3) check which of them has which of the colors

Comment: And all of the squares may end up having different colors... I need to be more specific, sorry :P

Comment: You say that you need undefined number of #box with different colors? This is more complex that we are explained here

Comment: I'll edit my question in a second with new results. The first part is less complex, than it seemed to be. The only struggle is passing the data on which color is used on which id. Check the example page as well

Comment: Oh, if no there are your modifications I was confused because I don't know what are you trying to do. But now I think that I understand you. To get current color of your boxes you can add onclick to them and get with the `getColor() ` function that I write to you only editing the selector in getElementById

Comment: So the simpliest way would be:
1) Filling the squares with desired colors
2) getColor() on form submit
3) sending the data to php
4) other stuff that I will handle :P

Anyway colors are just indicators so I need **either** color or an ID. The colors are just to make a future interface look a bit simplier. The whole thing would finally look a bit like that http://shrt.edu.pl/jcOo8oWuaH1wLa2